# Connecting to Identity Web service running on Host from .net Core api running inside container (hosted in windows) gives error 400 Bad Request

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-network

Expected Behavior:

I am able to make my api run in a container so far. The api should be able to connect to an Identity Server running on my host machine at: `http://localhost:26019/` .

Actual Behavior:

Unfortunately the error from the container is:

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request)
```

I am able from my api to contact a SQL Server database on the host machine through a connection string that is:

```
"Database": "Data Source=docker.for.win.localhost,1433;Database=.;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=false;User Id=AppUser;Password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

Similarly, I am trying to contact the Identity Web service running on the host through the connection string:

```
"AuthorityUrl": "http://docker.for.win.localhost:26019"
```

Unfortunately I don't manage to hit the service. What am I missing? Thanks in advance!